# JQuery Datatables Pagination with selected check boxes. Checkboxes will only work on current pagination page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I want to get the values of all selected checkboxes , but currently it gives only current page. Pls advice

```
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox" name="emails[]" value=' . $user['id'] . '>
```

Comment: What does your jQuery/JavaScript look like to read the boxes?

Comment: @Dean.DePue : didn't use jquery for read,         $formData = $this->request->getParams();
        $users = $formData['emails']; I used this on my Controller, at it returns only current page data. pls advice

Comment: Youll need to implement your own custom functionality to temporarily store the IDs for each row that changes and the changes made. The issue is that the rows are added to the DOM *only* for the currently displayed page. When you change the page, the last's pages rows are removed from the DOM and the new ones are added.